# Error sinking/scanning parquet file in Polars

Tags: parquet, python-polars

I'm getting the following error type when trying to read/scan a parquet file I just saved:
`arrowerrorexception: externalformat("file out of specification: repetition level must be defined for a primitive type")`

The lazy dataframe sinks to parquet just fine (I think), and has the following column types:`cat`, `date`, `f32`

Comment: It's probably something that should be reported to the issues tracker. Can you create a reproducible example?

Comment: `df = pl.LazyFrame([{'col1':  'abcd1', 'date': '2023-04-24', 'number' :12.123}])
(df.select(
    pl.col('col1').cast(pl.Categorical),
    pl.col('date').str.to_date('%Y-%m-%d'),
    pl.col('number').cast(pl.Float32),))

df.sink_parquet('test.parquet') #this doesn't give an error
pl.scan_parquet('test.parquet')`

Comment: If you can replicate the failing test case, it could be reported to https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/